# Win7 - DVD drive spins up but fails to read, fails write

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, dvd, optical-drive

Running Windows 7 x64. DVD drive is a BenQ DC DQ60 ATA dvd-dl rw. Everything functions correctly in linux, and I can boot to cd/dvds, so the drive itself does work.

Symptom: when I insert any CD or DVD (burned or retail), the drive spins up the disk, and (usually) displays the disk title in My Computer, but just continues to spin indefinitely. I cannot browse the disk in the drive, install from it, or read anything.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is something like SecuROM or something else that is running afoul on your system? I understand it may not be realistic to check, but have you performed a clean install of Windows  and seen the same behavior?

Comment: Something like this had occurred to me. This is a relatively clean installation, with only some Steam games installed. I did uninstall daemon tools lite, but to no avail.

Comment: Check the DMA status of the drive by looking at the properties of the controller the drive is attached to. I once had this problem because windows had downgraded the transfer rate to PIO mode. Windows (used to at least) use some sort of counter for errors and steps down transfer rate for after X number of errors. The counter never resets which makes sense for a hard drive, but for removable media is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to remark that BenQ doesn't seems to supply a Windows driver for DQ60, so it seems you're dependent on the default Windows driver. If you've received a CD with a driver for it, make sure it's installed. Whatever is the current driver, apparently it doesn't work real well.

As far as reviews go, the DQ60 gets very bad reviews, usually with the advice of having it replaced for BENQ 1640. If this is a new computer, make sure that it's really the DQ60 in the specs - if not you may ask to have it replaced. In any case, I must say that I'm not at all impressed by the website of BenQ.

Comment: DQ60 had very good reviews when I got it years ago... largely because of good firmware support. But I agree, the BenQ support site now is atrocious. I'm using the built-in Windows driver, that seems to have correctly detected the drive.

Comment: You do not need special drivers for ATAPI devices on Windows, just like you do not need special drivers for hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a virus or other DRM garbage on your Windows machine which has installed a lower or upper filter on the drive (The Sony/BMG rootkit did this, for example). Find and remove the filter (pull up the drive's advanced properties in Device Manager and have a look through the dropdown list for filters).